# Add JPanel in arraylist<JPanel>

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel

I have a `JPanel` called `parentPanel`.
Also I have other `sonPanels` in `parentPanel`.

I want to remove the `sonPanels` and add them in an `arraylist<JPanel>`

Can you help me??

Thanks in advance!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JPanel inherits from Container, you can use the [getComponents() method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29) to get the list of your sonPanels.

After getting them all, you can clear you parentPanel by calling the [removeAll() method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll%28%29).
If you had a `deleteRows` method, simply call the first method on your `JPanel`, lets call it `contentPane`, and then call the second method to remove.

```
public Component[] getAndClearSonPanels() {
    Component[] currentComponents = contentPane.getComponents();
    contentPane.removeAll();
    return currentComponents;
}
```

If you need to traverse even more deeply into each of the JPanels, you would need to, recursively do so.